# Spawning child processes returns invalid argument

Tags: emacs, clojure, cider

I have a class this semester that requires a lisp dialect so I'm trying to get started with Clojure but I'm running into a lot of problems setting up my environment.

I'm on a Windows machine and am following the tutorial at http://www.braveclojure.com/basic-emacs/ to set up emacs which from my research seems like the best IDE for working with lisp. I had Cygwin installed before starting which supposedly has a lot of support for emacs but I'm not sure if I need to do more than just have it installed.

My problems is when I try to start a REPL in emacs with M-x cider-jack-in I get the response Spawning child process: invalid argument. If I do the M-x load-path command I get a list of every subfolder in my .emacs.d folder but not the .d folder itself but the folder where my cider package is installed is clearly listed.

I installed lein before I decided to try setting up emacs and I could open a REPL just fine with it but emacs seems like a much better way of working than just using the terminal.

Any advice is greatly appreciated but if there is a better/easier way to get started with Clojure on Windows than what I'm currently doing I'd love to hear about it.

Thanks in advance for any replies.

Comment: Try [NightCode](https://sekao.net/nightcode/) or [LightTable](http://lighttable.com/). Either of these is a good way to start using Clojure. These and other resources are mentioned [here](http://clojure.org/community/resources).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, emacs is great, but if you haven't worked with it before then you will have a very steep learning curve, exacerbated by the fact you are running Windows. I myself use emacs with CIDER a lot, and I also use emacs on Windows quite a bit, but I don't mix it - I use emacs/CIDER only on Linux. It doesn't mean at all that it can't be made to work on Windows, it's just it has a lot of complexity of its own, which you might not have time or inclination to deal with right now. (By the way, I wouldn't recommend using emacs under Cygwin [1] , use a [good native build](http://emacsbinw64.sourceforge.net/) instead. And if you still decide to go with emacs, by all means try [Prelude](https://github.com/bbatsov/prelude) - it comes from the author of CIDER by the way.)

If you want an option that is definitely smoother under the circumstances, download [IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/) and install [Cursive](https://cursive-ide.com/). That will have its own learning curve for sure, but give it a try and see what you prefer. I use *both*, nothing beats IntelliJ/Cursive in Java interop projects.

Both emacs/CIDER and IntelliJ/Cursive are terrific and will repay for deeper learning.

---

[1] I am not even sure a combination of emacs on Cygwin and lein/clojure on Win32 can work, but I have no environment to test.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I'll try out IntelliJ.I think you are right about running things on windows is adding too much complexity for what I want to do. I guess if all else fails I can always set up Linux :)

Answer (score -1):

unset the SHELL env variable - taken from: http://tb-nguyen.blogspot.com/2010/05/how-to-fix-emacs-windows-error-spawning.html

It worked for me